# get row and column depending on value using SQL?

Tags: sql, pivot, transpose

I got a couple of tables with rows and columns. In some there is an X and in some not. Now I would like to get all row-column pairs that have an X in there.

Is that possible with SQL? Would it be possible with somehow else?

One idea I had was using `case`, but I would need to hard code all the col/row combinations.

### Example

**Table:**

```
rowNo| col1 | col2 | colN
-----|------|------|----
row1 |  X   |      |
row2 |  X   |   X  |
rowN |      |      |
```

**Expected result:**

```
| row | col |
| ----|---- |
| row1|col1 |
| row2|col1 |
| row2|col2 |
```

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc...) that you are using.

Comment: @YogeshSharma I am open for all DBMS - I need this for a one time migration - it doesn't matter

Comment: So you will migrate to another dbms just to fit the answer here?

Comment: @jarlh - currently I have unnormalized data in very bad shape - and we don't know yet what the target solution will be - so every DBMS will do it's job to bring the data in shape, so we can move it to whatever we'll decide on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `union all` :

```
select t.rowno, t.col 
from ( select rowno, col1 as col 
       from table t
       union all
       select rowno, col2
       from table t
       . . .
     ) t
where col = 'X';
```

If you are working with `SQL Server`, then you can `apply` :

```
select t.rowNo as row, tt.col
from table t cross apply
     ( values (col1), (col2), . . . ,(coln) 
     ) tt(col)
where tt.col = 'X';
```